# What does my class have to include to use content_tag() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, actionview

I had some nice helper method `three_columns` in my ApplicationHelper which I want to separate now into its own class to prevent naming collisions.

```
# In my ApplicationHelper I have this:
def three_columns(&block)
  ThreeColumns.new(&block)
end

# And in a separate file:
class ThreeColumns
  include ActionView::Context
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  def initialize(&block)
    content_tag(:div, class: :three_columns) do
      capture(self, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to use this like `<%= three_columns { .. } %>`, but I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `capture_haml' for #<ThreeColumns:0x007fa5a235a030 @output_buffer=nil>
```

So what do I have to do make the HAML stuff available to my ThreeColumns class?

Thank you.